# Standard deviation of a coin flip bet

Tags: binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

What is the standard deviation for the pay-offs of a coin flipping game where you get 2 dollars if heads and lose 1 dollar if tails.  How does the standard deviation change if the probabilities remain constant but the pay-off changes to 3 dollars for heads and lose 1 for tails.  What is the generalized formula for standard deviation in a coin flip with given probabilities and pay-offs?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If so, you should tag it as self study, and lay out to the readers of CrossValidated where you're stuck and/or what you've tried/considered to this point to try and solve this problem.  thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to work out the expectation? What about the variance?

Comment: Upon observing this is a scaled Bernoulli distribution, the formula follows immediately by scaling the SD of a Bernoulli variate.

Comment: The original double or nothing game has the pay-off of 1 or -1. I am afraid that the initial question of @user26809 was this.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant Formula

[image]

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

---

For pay-off of 2, -1 and probabilities of 50%/50%.

Expected value = 0.50*2+.50*-1 = .50

Variance = 0.50*(2-.50)^2 + 0.50*(-1-.50)^2 = 2.25

SD = 2.25^(1/2) = 1.5

---

For pay-off of 3, -1 and probabilities of 50%/50%.

Expected value = 0.50*3+.50*-1 = 1

Variance = 0.50*(3-1)^2 + 0.50*(-1-1)^2 = 4

SD = 4^(1/2) = 2